# Web Setup Project on Visual Studio 2022 - Unable to open project error

Tags: visual-studio-2022, web-setup-project

Good evening,

I have created a Web Form using Visual Studio 2022, and I have created a Web Setup project to help our customers to install the site on their server. I used the official extension that allows to create Setup projects in VS2022 (Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects); everything worked fine until some days ago, when VS2022 started to show the following error when trying to load the installer project:

"Unable to open project .../Setup.vdproj".

This is the error I am getting when I try to open/create a Web Setup project

[image: 1]

I tried to open it also with VS2019, which I still had installed on my computer, but I got the same error.

At the beginning I thought it was an issue related to the project (maybe for some reasons some files had been corrrupted), so I tried to create a new Web Setup project, both on VS2022 and VS2019. Again, the same error appeared, on both versions of VS. At this point I tried to load the already existing project on another computer, and on the other computer everything worked perfectly, the project was loaded immediatly and no issues have been detected.
I tried to unistall and re-install the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects extension, it didn't solve the problem; I tried to repair VS2022, it didn't solve the problem; I tried to completely uninstall VS2022 and VS2019 and re-install only VS2022, and guess what? It didn't solve the problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem, and what is the reason why I am unable to neither load nor create Web Setup projects?

Thank you,
Giacomo